# How can I replicate the 'Walk' data pattern in C?

Tags: c, memory, memory-leaks

I've been trying to work out a simple way of representing the 'Walk' data pattern for DRAM as shown in this paper: http://www.pdl.cmu.edu/PDL-FTP/NVM/dram-retention_isca13.pdf

The basic idea is that you have a stream of memory bits/cells that you wish to access. In this case I want to access with a value of '1' in each cell at a different location until I have accessed each memory cell.

A diagrammatic representation of what I mean is this:

```
0001 <- 1st iteration
0100 <- 2nd iteration
1000 <- 3rd iteration
0010 <- 4th iteration
```

Is there a way to program this in C using a simple for loop that appends a '1' in a random index each time and in each iteration remove the '1' from the previous iteration and append another '1' until all indexes have been populated?

This is my most recent attempt, if anybody can build on what I have given the criteria that would be amazing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int memory[16];
bool accessed[sizeof(memory)];

int main()
{

    // Initially populate with zeros 
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(memory); i++)
    {
        memory[i] = 0;
        accessed[i] = false;

        printf("%d", memory[i]); 
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(memory); i++)
    {
        int randIdx = rand() % sizeof(memory);
        memory[randIdx] = 1;
        printf("%d", memory[i]);
    }



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Given that your `memory` is of type `int`, the loop `for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(memory); i++)
    {
        memory[i] = 0;` is running way out of bounds (unless `sizeof(int) == sizeof(char)`, which isn't impossible but is very unlikely).

Comment: Hi Jonathan, that's not a bad suggestion but I'd much rather replicate the walk data pattern from the paper I linked... Is there a way to generate random numbers (to represent indexes to access) and ensure that each random index is unique? e.g. ideally 4 2 1 3 rather than an erroneous result like 4 4 3 2

Comment: The relevant information is there in my question Jonathan. The question isn't what is walk data pattern? It is, how may I replicate (from my description of it based on information from the paper) in C. If you can't be of further help then let's pass the baton to someone else.

Comment: AFAICS, the patterns and sequence in the paper are anything but random.  Use an array to store the correct sequence.  Visit in the correct sequence.  I may have missed something, but the walk section in the paper does not seem to be about random visitations but about carefully crafted sequences of visitations.